# “How to fix ‘TweepError: Twitter error response: status code = 400’ error in python”

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to write a simple twitter bot using python and tweepy to script twitter data using the twitter API. The code is as follows

```
import csv
import tweepy
import argparse
import pandas as pd
####input your credentials here
consumer_key = '************************'
consumer_secret = '**************************************'
access_token = '**************************************'
access_token_secret = '***************************************'
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth,wait_on_rate_limit=True
# Open/Create a file to append data
csvFile = open('result1.csv', 'a')
#Use csv Writer
csvWriter = csv.Writer(csvFile)
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q="#Russia",count=100,
                           lang="en",
                           since="2017-04-03").items():
    print (tweet.created_at, tweet.text)
```

### this is the error message am getting:

```
    107         if self.index >= len(self.results) - 1:
--> 108             data = self.method(max_id=self.max_id, parser=RawParser(), *self.args, **self.kargs)
    109 
    110             if hasattr(self.method, '__self__'):

D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\binder.py in _call(*args, **kwargs)
    248             return method
    249         else:
--> 250             return method.execute()
    251 
    252     # Set pagination mode

D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\binder.py in execute(self)
    232                     raise RateLimitError(error_msg, resp)
    233                 else:
--> 234                     raise TweepError(error_msg, resp, api_code=api_error_code)
    235 
    236             # Parse the response payload

TweepError: Twitter error response: status code = 400
```

What I expected is to have a CSV file in my root folder but the CSV file is empty because the code didn't run perfectly. I did try the options, but don't see any difference.

Comment: As per official docs : https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/response-codes.html , It is either invalid request or you have not provided the correct credentials.